# Xcode 11 Objective C++ - Can't separate implementation from Header in ObjectiveC++ Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I have created an Xcode standard Objective-C Project wanting to test integration with C++.
I have renamed my file accordingly to .mm etc.

I have created a C++ Class with a .hpp header and a .cpp imp file.
This is the header

```
class a {
private:
   int anInt = 1;
public:
    int getAnInt();
};
```

this is the imp

```
#include "PrismMatricies.hpp"

int a::getAnInt() {return anInt;}
```

in my ViewController.mm file I do this after importing the .hpp header

```
a ar;
NSLog(@"Some Log %i", ar.getAnInt());
```

Build Error Code in Xcode = 
Undefined symbol: a::getAnInt()

If I move the function definition inside the header like this

```
class a {
private:
   int anInt = 1;
public:
    int getAnInt();
};

int a::getAnInt() {return anInt;}
```

The project works

Can anyone explain this to me as I simply don't get it

Comment: Note that "undefined symbol" is a link error, not a compile error. It sounds like your .cpp file isn't being linked into your build target. Make sure it's included in your build target's "compile sources" list.

Comment: You just answered the question. For some reason Xcode had not ticked Target Membership on the .cpp file. NEVER would have thought of something as simple as this... Thanks... Please answer the question so that I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "undefined symbol" is a link error, not a compile error, and your code certainly looks correct.

You will get that error if your .cpp isn't being linked into your build target. Make sure it's included in your build target's "compile sources" list. (You can also check that the target membership box is ticked in the File Inspector utility pane.)